# Llamar a una Funcion TypeScript desde Script JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy creando un script en un Componente y necesito ejecutar una función TypeScript al momento que el método éxito.
***Creación de script en componente Angular:***

```
let node = document.createElement('script');
node.src = 'https://pagos-box.com/checkout/asdasdasd/v52/main.min.js';
node.onload = () => {
  console.log('Script cargado!!!');
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = `module`;
  script.text = `
    var orderId = '${this.orderId}';
    var exito = function (data) {

      this.test01(data); ----> **Esta función está en TS**

    };      
    var error = function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      return;
    };
  `;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
}
node.onerror = (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  alert('Ocurrió un problema, vuelta a intentarlo más tarde');
}    
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
```

Necesito obtener el valor de esa data para trabajar con ella.

el método es solo una alerta

En su defecto poder utilizar los métodos de ese script y utilizarlo como métodos de Angular.

De antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: y si utilizas el objeto window en tu variable para que tu scope sea mas amplio, window.data = cuaqluiervalor

Answer (score 0):

no sé si conseguiste solucionar el problema. A mi me esta pasando algo parecido y lo que he hecho para solucionarlo es:
declarar una variable global (yo la he puesto debajo de los import):
var _this: any;

establecer el valor de _this antes de ejecutar la función javascript:
_this = this

utilizar _this en la función de retorno:
_this.test01(data)

Si no lo has resuelto aún espero que te ayude algo
Un saludo

Comment: Al final lo hice con un tag HTML llamando una función en AJAX